# PHP to Objective C (iPhone App) Communication

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an iPhone app that posts data to a php app which in turn stores this data in a remote mysql database.

I wanted the php file to inform the iphone app whether or not the storage was successful. Here is my php code:

```
<?php

//connect to database
function connect() {
  $dbh = mysql_connect ("localhost", "123", "456789") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("PDS", $dbh); 
  return $dbh;
}

//store posted data
if(isset($_POST['message'])){
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $dbh = connect();
  $query = "INSERT INTO  messages (message) VALUES ('$message')";
  $result = mysql_query( $query ) or die ("didn't query");        
}
?>
```

1) How would I modify the php file above to echo something based on the success/failure of the requested SQL query?

2) What part of the objective C API handles reading in php variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct communication between Objective-C and PHP. You query a Web-URL in Objective-C using NSURLConnection or better yet [ASIHttp](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use). The queried resource then does something with the parameters you're giving it (in your case, by posting to it) and returns something. Generally, you agree on a standard (say, JSON) to communicate beforehand, or just use HTTP-Statuscodes for this kind of stuff. Than you can exmaine the response given by the NSURLConnection (look at the docs) and find out what happend on the server

Update: ASI-Http has the advantage of being more straight forward to use, it encapsulates a lot of low-level stuff for you. Otherwise, it does the same thing that NSURLConnection does

Next Update:
Here's the solution with ASIHTTP and correct String parsing. This uses HTTP Get, put post won't be much more difficult

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request startSynchronous];
NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) {
  NSString *response = [request responseString];
  NSArray *results = [response componentsSeparatedByString:@", "]; 
  for (NSString* result in results) {
   NSString * trimmedResult = [result stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
   if ([trimmedResult isEqualToString:@"failure"]) 
    NSLog(@"operation %i failed.", i + 1);
   }
 }
```

Comment: why is ASIHTTP better than NSURLConnection?

Answer (score 1):

Just make the php echo directly onto the page and have the iPhone app get the contents of the page and parse them.

e.g. If the php pages echoes `success, failure, success`, you could use:

```
NSString *contents = readthepage (google how to do this)
NSArray *results = [contents componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
for (int i = 0; i < [results count]; i++) {
    NSString *result = [results ObjectAtIndex:i];
    if ([result rangeOfString:@"failure"].length > 0) // this isn't the perfect test, it checks whether _result_ contains the string @"failure", not is equal to. If it matters to you, find a different method.
        NSLog(@"operation %i failed.", i + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't test NSString equality like that. Instead you must do [result isEqualToString:@"failure"] for example. Here, you're testing pointer equality rather than value equality.

Comment: I realized that as I was writing it, I just forgot the right way to write it. From my experience, `isEqualToString` doesn't always work correctly either. I usually use `rangeOfString`.

Comment: you should trim your result strings before comparing then obviously